# Taking second-by-second data and transforming it into hour-by-hour?

Tags: aggregate

So, I have a dataset that contains values sampled every second.

I would like to transform the above dataset that has the second-by-second data, so that it is indexed every hour.  And the value at each hour is the running sum total through the day.

I haven't been able to find anything similar in my searches, so if anyone could point me in the best direction to find out the best method to accomplish this; it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you are using to implement this as well as the greater context of your application, but generally a running sum is fairly simple in most cases.  For instance, if you are using a language such as the one in Matlab, there are functions that allow you to sum all of the contents in an array (as you would in Excel).  Other languages have libraries or packages you can call on to do this also, and I recommend looking it up if you are using anything higher level than, say, C.

However, let's assume you want to write your own function to do this.  The way that jumps to my mind is a single iteration through your data array.  Say your array has *n* elements in it.  With your loop, designate a variable, and in each loop iteration, increase the value via a sum, for example:

`my $sum = $dataArray[0];     # running sum tracker, initialize to first value
for ($i=1; $i < <length of your array>; $i++) {
  $sum += $dataArray[$i];
}`

In the end, this loop would have complexity O(*n*).  I would also then add a conditional in the loop to throw the sum for index $i into some other data structure and index it with $i when $i is a multiple of seconds in an hour (3600 samples).  My favorite way to do that would probably a hash or associative array to map `$i => $sum` pairs as this would allow me to track EXACTLY where cut off each running sum. But there's no reason a plain old array can't suffice if you are willing to write the code to convert your 1:n indices into "time" and just assume they correspond to "hour 0, hour 1, hour 2 ....".

WARNING:  If you do this, I caution you that there is no substitute for having timestamps with your data.  Sampling rate can have hardware drift or approximation error while scripting, and this can lead to significant skew in time vs. data accounting if you are not careful.